# Change button's font size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change font size on button but have had no success

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-b">
   <div class="ui-block-a">
     <input type="button" value="Open" onclick="ZZ();">
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-b">
     <input type="button" value="close">
   </div>
   <div class="ui-block-c">
     <input type="button" value="BUG">
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

I've tried this, but it won't change the font size:

```
<div class="ui-block-c">
  <input  style="font-size:10px;" type="button" value="BUG">
</div>
```

Comment: you want to change it dynamically or what?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8ae5hq74/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much I have understood, you want to change font size of button.

**Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu7dn1yg/1/)**

I have just added a "class" attribute which has been set in css. 
like

```
  <input type="button" value="Test Button" class="btnClass"/>
```

and css code:

```
 .btnClass {
            font-size: 12px;
           }
```

You may set size as per your need.

If you want to change is dynamically, you can use .addClass method. [jquery document](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) for the same

If haven't got you correctly please come again.